# about Action scripts ... cannot make an object follow my mouse

Tags: actionscript-3

I just started learning Flash prof. and Action script 3.0, and for the easiest beginning, I started with the goal of making an object that follows my mouse. I took a look at how people code their games and wrote my own code:

```
package
{
private class def 
{
    private static const speed:Number = 3;
    private var player:square;
}
private function
{
    var mousex = mouseX;
    var mousey = mouseY;
    var movx = 0;
    var movy = 0;

    if ( player.x < mousex)
    {
        movx = 1
    }
    else if ( player.x > mousex )
    {
        movx = -1
    }
    if ( player.y < mousey )
    {
        movy = 1
    }
    else if ( player.y > mousey )
    {
        movy = -1
    }
    if ( movx > 0 )
    {
        if ( player.x + speed < mousex )
        {
            player.x +=speed 
        }
    else if ( movx < 0 )
    {
        if ( player.x - speed > mousey )
        {
            player.x -= speed
        }
    }
    if (movy > 0 )
    {
        if ( player.y + speed < mousey )
        {
            player.y += speed
        }
    else if ( movy < 0 )
    {
        if ( player.y - speed > mousey )
        {
            player.y -= speed
        }

    }
    }
    }
}
}
```

and I got these errors :

```
Error : Packages cannot be nested.
Error : The private attribute may be used only on class property definition. 
Error : Syntax error : expecting  identifier before leftbrace. 
Error : .............: ...........leftparen before leftbrace .
Error : .............: ........... rightparen before leftbrace.
```

Any help? I have never used any computer languages before.

Answer (score 0):

There are many syntax errors. A package must have a name. A class in inside a package, and a function inside a class, like this:

```
package mypackage { 
    public class MyClass { 
        public function MyFunction() { 
            // my function code
            ...
        } 
    } 
}
```

Moreover, you should not declare everything as private. Only the elements that must not be accessed from outside of the class.

You should start by following some tutorials about AS3 fundamentals on [Adobe Website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html). If you're interested in coding games [Emanuele Feronato](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/)'s blog will be a good place for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are lot of braces.

I would suggest you to do the following steps:

1. Create a simple package and compile it successfully
2. Write an empty class in the package and then compile
3. Draw some object on screen when the class is loaded. That's it
4. Add functionality to click the object
5. print something when the object is clicked